# Clarification about this step in matrix proof?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a matrix of rank $r$ of order $n \times m$ and suppose it can be partitioned into pieces $A_{11},A_{12},A_{21},A_{22}$, where the leading minor $A_{11}$ is of size $r \times r$ and is non-singular.

In a proof, my textbook uses the following property:

> If $A_{11}^-$ is the inverse of $A_{11}$, then by the construction there is a matrix $B$ such that $[A_{21}, A_{22}] = B [ A_{11}, A_{12}]$

It doesn't elaborate/explain, and I'm unsure how exactly this is justified.

Intuitively, I suppose it is because $A$ is of rank $r$, and the sub-matrix $A_{11}$ is also of rank $r$. Could someone explain this step to me?

Comment: If it was not the case, either $A_{11}$ would not be full rank or the rank of $A$ would be strictly more than $r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $A$ is split into two rows $[A_{11}, A_{12}]$ (top) and $[A_{21}, A_{22}]$ (bottom). Since the total rank is $r$ and the top row already has rank $r$, each of the bottom rows is a linear combination of some of the first $r$ rows. Denoting $A_j$ for the $j$th row of $A$, this means for each $i > r$ there are coefficients $b_{ij}$ such that

$$A_i = \sum_{1\leq j \leq r}b_{ij}A_j$$

These coefficients populate a $(n-r)\times r$ matrix $B = (b_{ij})$, with $BA_{11} = A_{21}$ and $BA_{12} = A_{22}$.

Comment: thanks a lot, that makes a lot of sense